# CSS attributes not applying

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <title>HTML5/CSS3 Responsive Theme</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <header class="mainheader">
        <img src="img.jpg">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
body {
    background-image: url(img1.jpg);
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    font-family: Arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode";
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited; {
}
a:hover, a:active; {
}
.body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}
.mainheader img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2% 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainheader nav {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainheader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainheader nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited, {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}
.mainheader nav a:hover, .mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.mainheader nav ul li a{
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

> All the attributes you see here are working except those within .mainheader nav a:link , .mainheader nav a:visited. (color: #FFF; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 25px; height: 20px;) You asked to see more code, here it is. Thanks

Comment: We'll need to see your HTML as well to tell you exactly why the attributes aren't applying. You may have an `a` color that is overriding these pseudo-selectors with greater specificity.

Comment: you have to post all relevant HTML, so that we can see its structure (and also the other CSS, there might be overwriting rules)

Comment: we also need to see your other css rules. A likely issue is that some other rule has greater [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: please try to style the a tag without pseudo-classes (only .mainheader nav a)

Comment: Please post HTML

Comment: remove the comma from the end line of your CSS class declaration here:
`.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited, {` that last comma is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will not apply. Why?

> You have a ***syntax error*** `,` comma after the selector.

Try changing this to:

`.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited,`

to:

`.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}
```